# How can I rename files only if they don't match a pattern?

Tags: bash, file, rename

I want to rename files by appending "-renamed" to the basename before the extension, but I also don't want to rename files that already have the "-renamed" string.

For example,

```
IMG_1234.jpg -> IMG_1234-renamed.jpg
IMG_1235.mp4 -> IMG_1235-renamed.mp4
IMG_1236-renamed.jpg -> no change
```

For the first part, I have the following working:

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv $f ${f%.jpg}-renamed.jpg; done
for f in *.mp4; do mv $f ${f%.mp4}-renamed.mp4; done
```

How can I assure that subsequent runs won't create keep adding the string over and over?

```
IMG_1234-renamed.jpg -> IMG_1234-renamed-renamed.jpg
IMG_1235-renamed.mp4 -> IMG_1235-renamed-renamed.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extended globbing:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for f in !(*-renamed).@(jpg|mp4) ; do
    new=${f%.*}
    new+=-renamed.${f##*.}
    if [[ -e $new ]] ; then
        echo Skipped: "$new" already exists. >&2
    else
        mv "$f" "$new"
    fi
done
```

- `!(*-renamed)` will match anything that doesn't end in `-renamed`;
- `@(jpg|mp4)` matches `jpg` or `mp4`;
- `${f##*.}` returns the extension (even if the basename contains several dots).
- Also, quote your variables so the script works for file names containing whitespace.
- Moreover, check for the existence of the target file so you don't accidentally overwrite a previously renamed file.

Comment: I've studied `man bash` and [Adnvanced Bash Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), but there probably many more recent online resources to study, too.