# Why doesn't this Bash globbing pattern work?

Tags: bash, glob

I was reading this [answer on how to use negated glob patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68770082/58808) in Bash and I'm wondering why this glob pattern works:

```sh
$ ls !(*-renamed).jpg
IMG_1234.jpg
```

But this one does not:

```sh
$ ls *!(-renamed).jpg
IMG_1234.jpg         IMG_1236-renamed.jpg
```

Is it because `*` is too greedy? Or does it behave differently inside parentheses? I couldn't find an explanation in the Bash manual.

Comment: This has also been discussed briefly on the bug-bash mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-04/msg00205.html

Comment: @oguzismail thanks. Indeed, I had no idea a negated pattern can match an empty string. That was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `*` matches `IMG_1236-renamed`, `!(-renamed)` matches an empty string, and `.jpg` matches itself.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the negated pattern can match an empty string. The link posted by Oğuz above helped too.